# How to fetch product data from WooCommerce API into my react native app

Tags: react-native, woocommerce

I am news to react native. I had build up a localhost WordPress + WooCommerce Site, and I am trying to fetch the product details exp: price, name and etc to my react native app. I had installed the "woocommerce-api" package. I can fetch some product details from "http://localhost:8888/foodSite/wp-json/wp/v2/product" but cannot fetch details from "http://localhost:8888/foodSite/wp-json/wc/v2/products". Can someone point out my problems?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
                                   url: 'http://localhost:8888/foodSite/',
                                   consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxx',
                                   consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxx',
                                   wpAPI: true,
                                   version: 'wc/v2'
                                   });

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

state={
data:[]
}



fetchData = async()=>{
const response = await
fetch('http://localhost:8888/foodSite/wp-json/wp/v2/product?per_page=100');

const posts = await response.json();

this.setState({data:posts});
}

componentDidMount(){
this.fetchData();
}



render() {
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Product</Text>

        <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i}
        renderItem={({item})=>
        <View style={styles.postColumn}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:18,fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.id}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize:18,fontWeight:'bold'}}>{WooCommerce.get('products').name}</Text>
        </View>
        }
        />
        </View>
        );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',[enter image description here][1]
 marginTop:40,
  },

});
```

Comment: I don't understand your real problem. Do you want to find the details of specific product?

Comment: no, i just want to retrieve some specific details for all the product, for example price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url is wrong, changed it as below. `wp` changed to `wc` and `product` to `products`

```
 http://localhost:8888/foodSite/wp-json/wc/v2/products?per_page=100
```

Doc Url: [WoocommerceRestApi](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products)

Comment: Thanks, i am able to fetch the product details now.

Comment: If my answer help you to solve your problem, please accept it by ticking the tick icon. Wc